# php contains a form with insecure endpoint

Tags: php, forms, security, https, module

I am having an issue here, I'm working on my own website for university however I have came across a problem I can't find the answer to anywhere. I have a product page and a php module that handles adding the item to cart session data, however I'm getting this error:

https://saturn.csit.rmit.edu.au/~s3482230/wp/a2/product.php?productid=P001' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'module: add to cart.php'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection. (the website is hosted on the school servers that you cant access without login on so you can't view it sadly.

but the form is writen as such...

```
<form class=productqty action="module: add to cart.php" method="post">
    <p id=price>$<span id=pricedouble>0</span></p>
    <input name="price" id=prodprice type="hidden" value="20.00" required/>
    <input name="product code" type="hidden" value="P001" required/>
    <input name="quantity" id=qtyinput maxlength="3" type="text" value="1" 
    onblur='checkButtons()' onkeypress='checkIfNumber(event)' required/>
    <button id=negativebutton type="button" onclick="minusOne()" disabled> - </button>
    <button id=positivebutton type="button" onclick="plusOne()"> + </button>
    <input type="submit" value="Purchase" />
</form>
```

and the module code that handles adding to session and cart is: (unfinished)

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

}

$_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['product code']]['qty'] = $_POST['quantity'];
$_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['product code']]['price'] = $_POST['price'];


header("Location: ".$_SESSION["redirect_url"]);
?>
```

NOTE: the redirect_url is being used to redirect after logging on and off and works on those modules so it should work here, have also tried commenting the redirect out but doesn't change the warning, I hope this is enough information.

Comment: `module: add to cart.php` is not a valid url... you have to put the url to the cart script (with a https: protocol specified).

Comment: it's located on the same directory and i have a .htaccess filetype on the server so this works and redirects any HTTP sites to be HTTPS instead. I have done exactly this for my 'login' and 'logout' .php modules and works fine.

Comment: module is not a valid url scheme.. the action attribute in your form has to be a valid url.... if `add_to_cart.php` is in the same directory as `product.php` then removing the "module: " text from your form action is all that is needed.

Comment: the name is 'module: add to cart.php' it's just my way of naming files to understand what file is what.

Comment: I would rename the file to remove the colon and spaces... normal convention would be to use hyphens in there place... i.e.  `module-add-to-cart.php`

Comment: I'll take that under advisement thanks, but that wouldn't help my current problem right now :P

Comment: thanks @Orangepill while not directly related doing that would have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED IT!

turns out, you can't use a lot of certain characters in the action="xxxx" method, I had to replace ':' with '%3A' and spaces with '%20'

so I used action="module%3A%20add%20to%20cart.php" and works fine.